# Get an element position in a DataFrame pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following problem:
After performing some operations on the input file "`pannelloBschema1_0.t19.glo`" (The "t19.glo" extension is nothing but a .txt file) I get the variable "`min_diff`", whose value is 0.7222780000000029. I would like to know how I can get the position (row) in which `"min_diff"` is. Then, I would need to take the value placed in the same row, but in the column whose header is "disp". I am stacked here. I tried with `index.get_indexer([min_diff])`, but it returns: array([-1], dtype=int64), so this is not the way. Can anyone help me out?

You can download "pannelloBschema1_0.t19.glo" here: [https://github.com/giadabart/sharedfiles](https://stackoverflow.com))

And here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

specificload_reading = np.loadtxt('pannelloBschema1_0.t19.glo', skiprows = 2)

lastline = (specificload_reading[-1][1] + specificload_reading[-1][2])/1000
lastline_reduced = 0.7 * lastline
laoddevelopment = [(el[2]+el[1])/1000 for el in specificload_reading]
dispdevelopment = [-el*1000 for el in specificload_reading[:,0]]

data = {
    "disp": dispdevelopment,
    "load": laoddevelopment,
    "70%load": lastline_reduced,
    "load_diff": laoddevelopment-lastline_reduced
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['abs_loaddiff']= (df['load'] - df['70%load']).abs()

somerows = df.iloc[0:3]

print(somerows)


min_diff = df['abs_loaddiff'].min()
print(min_diff) #>>> 0.7222780000000029

# index.get_indexer([item], method=…)
index.get_indexer([min_diff])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the following approach.

## Load data

First read data directly with pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

fn = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giadabart/sharedfiles/main/pannelloBschema1_0.t19.glo'

df = pd.read_csv(
    fn,
    skiprows=2,
    delim_whitespace=True,
    names=[0,1,2])
```

which looks like

```bash
          0          1         2
0  0.000417 -12132.530  12132.53
1  0.000395 -11108.940  12914.65
2  0.000374 -10082.920  13694.34
3  0.000353  -9054.317  14471.44
4  0.000332  -8024.002  15246.83
```

## Operations in pandas rather than list/numpy

```py
df["load"] = (df[1] + df[2]) / 1e3
df["disp"] = -df[0] * 1e3
# Here I'm not quite sure what are you going to archive
# but you can broadcast the result
df["load70%"] = (df.iloc[-1][1] + df.iloc[-1][2]) / 1e3 *.7
# and finally
df["abs_load_diff"] = (df["load"] - df["load70%"]).abs()
```

Now you can consider just the last 4 columns you just calculated

```py
df = df[['load', 'disp', 'load70%', 'abs_load_diff']]
```

which looks like

```bash
   load      disp      load70%        abs_load_diff
0  0.000000 -0.416960  123.871552     123.871552
1  1.805710 -0.395356  123.871552     122.065842
2  3.611420 -0.373848  123.871552     120.260132
3  5.417123 -0.352667  123.871552     118.454429
4  7.222828 -0.331626  123.871552     116.648724
```

## Get index for minimum value

In pandas this can be obtained via

```py
df['abs_load_diff'].idxmin()
```

which returns `69`. You can eventually isolate the given row(s) using

```py
df.iloc[df['abs_load_diff'].idxmin()]
```

which returns

```bash
load             124.593830
disp               1.452970
load70%          123.871552
abs_load_diff      0.722278
Name: 69, dtype: float64
```